# Python beautifulsoup find text in the script

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<script>
    
                 numSort('0418112115');

</script>
```

I'm trying to get the text inside of the Javascript using this!

```
R = LoginDone.Connect()

html = urlopen("https://xxcom")

soup = BeautifulSoup(R, "html.parser")

ts = soup.find_all('script')
print('ts = ', ts)
```

And I get the results like this

```
</script>, <script>
                                                numSort('1411220613');
                                            </script>, <script>
                                                numSort('0115280805');
                                            </script>, <script>
```

What I want is the numbers, The numbers are random.
How can I get the numbers clearly, I need a help.

Thanks!

Comment: `ts = soup.find_all('script').string` use this and let me know if it works.

Comment: If there is some error paste it here

Answer (score 0):

Take the actual response text and then apply regex to it and return all matches

```
import re
import requests

# response_text = requests.get("https://xxcom").content

response_text = '''
</script>, <script>
                                                numSort('1411220613');
                                            </script>, <script>
                                                numSort('0115280805');
                                            </script>, <script>'''

pattern = re.compile(r"numSort\('(\d+)'\)")
print(pattern.findall(response_text))
```

[image]